# C# - TCP Client does not receive server response

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, tcp

I am trying to create an asynchronous TCP client for Unity Game project. I am successfully creating a TCP socket connection however I am unable to receive any server response correctly.

Here is my TCP Client Listener code:

```
#region TCP Client

public static string ServerIP = "127.0.0.1";
public static int TCPPort = 8080;
private IPEndPoint serverTCPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), TCPPort);

public static Socket TCPClient;
public Thread SocketThread;
// ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.  
private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
    new ManualResetEvent(false);
private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
    new ManualResetEvent(false);
private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
    new ManualResetEvent(false);

// The response from the remote device.  
private static String response = String.Empty;

private void StartTCPClient()
{
    // Connect to a remote device.  
    try
    {
        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        TCPClient = new Socket(serverTCPEndPoint.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
        TCPClient.BeginConnect(serverTCPEndPoint,
            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), TCPClient);
        connectDone.WaitOne();

        // Receive the response from the remote device.  
        TCPReceive();
        receiveDone.WaitOne();

        // Write the response to the console.  
        Debug.Log("Response received: " + response);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Complete the connection.  
        TCPClient.EndConnect(ar);

        Debug.Log("Socket connected to: " + TCPClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
        // Signal that the connection has been made.  
        connectDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.ToString());
    }
}

private void TCPReceive()
{
    try
    {
        // Create the state object.  
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = TCPClient;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
        TCPClient.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.ToString());
    }
}

private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        Debug.Log("RECEIVING");
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket   
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;

        // Read data from the remote device.  
        int bytesRead = TCPClient.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Get the rest of the data.  
            TCPClient.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        else
        {
            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.  
            if (state.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
                Debug.Log("RECEIVING 2: " + response);

                UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
                {
                    OnIncomingTCPData(response);
                });
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.  
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.ToString());
    }
}

#endregion
```

Here is how I start the client:

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    int accId = ClientLoginServer.accountId;
    DuloGames.UI.Demo_Chat.worldServer = this;
    if (accId != 0)
    {
        CursorMode cursorMode = CursorMode.Auto;
        Vector2 hotSpot = Vector2.zero;
        SocketThread = new Thread(StartTCPClient);
        SocketThread.IsBackground = true;
        SocketThread.Start();
        Cursor.SetCursor(brownCursor, hotSpot, cursorMode);
        //GameObject go = Instantiate(CharacterNamePrefab) as GameObject;
        GameObject CharacterSelectPanel = GameObject.Find("/Canvas/Panel/CharacterSelectPanel");
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad(worldserverConnection);
}
```

All I can see when server is sending data to the Unity TCP client listener is the following line:

```
Debug.Log("RECEIVING");
```

However this line seems to be not reachable:

```
Debug.Log("RECEIVING 2: " + response);
```

The following is allowing me to execute the called functions in the main unity thread.

```
UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
{
    OnIncomingTCPData(response);
});
```

Do you have any idea why my Asynchronous TCP client is not working correctly ?

Comment: You’re asking for more data indefinitely so it will block while waiting for more to arrive. If you don’t want it to block you’ll have to put it into non-blocking mode. Best way would be to have a protocol that doesn’t rely on pauses in data transfer. Also doesn’t make sense to use async socket and then make it into a sync one and put it into a thread. Why not just use sync if that’s how you want to use it?

Comment: See msdn samples.   The sample use Socket but you can replace socket with any class the inherits the socket like TcpClient : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen how can i put it into non-blocking mode ? Also which protocol you suggest ?

Comment: The protocol is up to you. I assume you had something already in mind since you need connections. You can just implement it now, it works. But don’t overcomplicate it. Either use sync or async, don’t use async with ManualResetEvents to make it sync.